# Ubuntu 14.04 network sharing asking for workgroup password

Tags: 14.04, samba

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 on my main PC and network sharing more or less was working.

Recently I've installed ubuntu 14.04 instead and after that all other ubuntu computers cannot access my main PC's shares, they all are asking for workgroup password - [image: http://i.imgur.com/gpKIxM3.png]

I've googled that topic and found about 20-30 advices all of which I've tried, including but not limited to (command and files might be inaccurate because I type as I remember, actual was 100% accurate as was copy and paste):

```
smbuseradd -a username  - added username and password combination aren't working
```

Hundreds of magical lines to add or edit in `smb.conf` like:

```
obey smth.. = no

guest share = yes

require password = no
```

And literally several dozens of different combinations

My current config file - http://pastebin.com/2aUFSqHV (it's pretty much default config)

I've restarted sambda, computer (both server and clients), routers.

Purged and reinstalled samba.

Copied some magical `smb.conf` configuration from the internet - neither of which help - it keep asking for workgroup password.

However all solutions above quite old - ranging from 0.5 years old to like 5-6 years.

I cannot use mount, command line, install dozens of other tools etc. To access it because of my family members who used to this workflow and have many devices.

Maybe someone know how to make samba shares work under Ubuntu 14.04, maybe some up to date solution

Comment: Can you please post the entire config?

Comment: @defeoct In the title you say that you are using 14.04, and in the body you say you have 12.04, so which is it?

Comment: @Toroidal: He *was* using Precise and upgraded to Trusty and that's when the problems started.

Comment: Thanks for response, I've added added my current config file  - http://pastebin.com/2aUFSqHV

Answer (score 1):

Check your hostname (machine name).  If it is over 15 characters windows machines can't handle it and don't see you in the workgroup!  The result is when you go to browse you are asking your own machine to let you see what's there based on the fact that technically you are the only one in the workgroup that is talking!  Therefore you are challenged by your own "Browse Master" which is you!

To fix by changing your hostname do the following:

`gksudo gedit /etc/hostname` (change to your desired hostname under 15 characters)

`gksudo gedit /etc/hosts` (change to your desired hostname under 15 characters)

then do...
`sudo service hostname restart`